# Pytest test working with different versions of program

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-markers

I have multiple tests which would work on different versions of my program.

For example testA is working only for versions 2,3,4 and not 5 and later. the other test is working for the test from version 4 and later. based on the pytest documentation, I can create a marker similar to below:

```
# content of test_mymodule.py
import mymodule

minversion3 = pytest.mark.skipif(
    myprogram.__versioninfo__ < 3, reason="at least version 3 is required"
)


@minversion3
def test_function():
    ...
```

minversion3 marks the tests to be run provided that program has at least version 3.
I would like to parametrize it so that I can have something like this:

```
@minmaxversion(3.2, 6.1)
def test_function():
    ...
```

so that this test is only working for programs with version minimum 3.2 and maximum 6.1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can wrap `pytest.mark.skipif` in a parametrized decorator to do what you want. The following code provides `minversion(n)` and `maxversion(n)` decorators that do exactly what you want; you can combine the two (see `test_function_2`) to set a version range, or you could of course write a new `minmaxversion` decoration following the same pattern:

```
import pytest

program_version = 6


def minversion(v):
    return pytest.mark.skipif(
        program_version < v, reason=f"Requires at least version {v}"
    )


def maxversion(v):
    return pytest.mark.skipif(
        program_version > v, reason=f"Requires at most version {v}"
    )


@maxversion(3)
def test_function_1():
    assert True


@maxversion(5)
@minversion(3)
def test_function_2():
    assert True
```

With `program_version = 6`, running the above code yields:

```
test_markers.py::test_function_1 SKIPPED (Requires at most version 3)  [ 50%]
test_markers.py::test_function_2 SKIPPED (Requires at most version 5)  [100%]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```py
# content of test_mymodule.py
import mymodule

minmaxversion = pytest.mark.skipif(
    myprogram.__versioninfo__ == 3.2 or myprogram.__versioninfo__ == 6.1,
    reason="Cannot run on 3.2 or 6.1"
)


@minmaxversion
def test_function():
    ...
```